# Pre-loader for Laravel requests

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, preloader

I have an application built in Laravel, the search on the homepage (home.blade.php) queries the DB and returns the results on the results page (results.blade.php). Now the app has been in use for some time there are 10-15K complex records being searched on a number of fields. We are using Elastic search to make the search as fast as possible, but it still takes around 10 seconds.

I'd like to display a pre-loader. Usually I would do this using ajax, or JS fired when (window).load is complete something like this:

```
var progress = setInterval(function () {
var $bar = $("#bar");

if ($bar.width() >= 600) {
    clearInterval(progress);
} else {
    $bar.width($bar.width() + 60);
}
$bar.text($bar.width() / 6 + "%");
if ($bar.width() / 6 == 100){
  $bar.text("Still working ... " + $bar.width() / 6 + "%");
}
}, 800);

$(window).load(function() {
$("#bar").width(600);
$(".loader").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

BUT the pre-loader is not appearing because Laravel is still on the previous (search) page, not yet loading the results page, in the process of querying the DB.

Is there a simple solution for making an ajax call to my Laravel controller, and displaying a pre-loader while it takes place? Ideally a way to keep track of the number of records searched by Laravel / Eloquent.

I'd like it to look something like this:
[image: preloader search searching php mockup]

> UPDATE:

It occurs to me I could fix this by returning the result as an api call

```
function resultsCall() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './myapiroute',
    data: "",
    success: function() {
        console.log("Loaded!");
    }
})
```

};

but i would like to avoid the extra security which comes with API calls - passing tokens / headers etc... I'm looking for a Laravel / php based solution if there is one.

Comment: _“there are 10-15K results being displayed”_ – don’t you think that’s rather the issue that should be fixed? No user wants to comb through ten thousands of search results displayed in one go … so it might make more sense to implement pagination for the search results.

Comment: The results are paginated. I need a preloader. I have updated my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: your preloader is working fine, but you don't get the response? Maybe that's an issue with your controller code.

If this is your question and you don't want to pass any types of headers, like tokens, using Laravel 5.2, define your route without assigning the api middleware. For Laravel 5.3 and 5.4, just define your route in the `routes/web.php` and you're already set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. No, the pre-loader is not working. I've updated the question